# Importing a JS module in a Typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am developing a website in TS in which I have to call an unofficial API, that is https://www.npmjs.com/package/reverso-api.
The whole module is written in JS, and as described in the docs, the proper way to import the module in JS is

```
const Reverso = require('reverso-api');
const reverso = new Reverso();
```

Unluckily, I am developing in TypeScript. I have no idea how to import the module in my project in order to make it works. How can I do that?

Comment: you could use this library instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ablanc/reverso-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this package doesn't have a type definition, you can use a temporary shorthand declaration so TypeScript won't yell at you. This makes all imports from `reverso-api` have `any` type, which you might have guessed is not very safe, but it's all we have right now.

```
declare module 'reverso-api';
```

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#shorthand-ambient-modules

Comment: Perfect!! So, considering the steps: 1) Go to node_modules/reverso-api, and create a index.d.ts, with `declare module 'reverso-api';` written inside. 2) in a file, for example, bar.ts, I have to import it with the statement `import {reverso-api} from reverso-api `?

Comment: @LeonardoCarlassare You can create a `.d.ts` file anywhere in your code, add this line and be done. Afterwards you can import and use this package as normal, nothing changes `const Reverso = require('reverso-api');` (just make sure this is the correct usage of the package). I don't recommend put the type declaration inside `node_modules` though, it should be checked in with git. If this helps, can you upvote and mark is the accepted answer to help others with the same question? ;)